# making apt-get package that depends on Node.js modules

Tags: node.js, apt

What is the right way to build a Ubuntu-style `apt-get` package that in fact depends on node.js and some of the NPM packages as well? Should we call "npm install" from the Makefile or what?

Answer (score 1):

you could do, best to do a check to make sure it is installed in the make file.

if not output a message telling them to npm install. you might even give a prompt to install npm - they then just hit YES and it does it all for them